# How do I make my figures fit on letter paper?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pdf, printing, graphics

I am looking for general ways to format figures in order to have them fit on a letter paper and look readable. Currently, my matplotlib figures get saved using pdf.savefig(). When I print using Adobe, the pdf is automatically scaled to fit on the letter paper. Rather than doing this, can I make these plots to fit by default? Below are some of the things I have tried to make this work.

```
with PdfPages('.pdf') as pdf: 

    plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
    plt.rc('font', size=8)
    plt.figure(figsize=(8.5,11))
    fig, axs2 = plt.subplots();
    list = [number1516,number1617,number,number1819]
    axs2.bar(['SY 1516','SY 1617','SY 1718', 'SY 1819'],list, color = ui2)
    axs2.set_title('Title')
    axs2.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    axs2.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
    axs2.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    axs2.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
    fig.suptitle('Main Title', va = 'top', ha= 'center')
    #plt.show()
    pdf.savefig(dpi = 300, orientation = 'portrait', bbox_inches = 'tight', papertype = 'letter')
```

After adjusting the figsize it seems the figure still appears small. I have attached the print preview  [print preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMoTI.png)

Comment: Change the `figsize` to fit on letter paper?  Its in inches, and letter is 8.5" wide by 11" tall.

Comment: I see, i didnt realize figsize units scale to inches @Jody Klymak

Comment: Old fashioned, I know, but typography predates metric...

Comment: sadly this didnt work, even when I change dpi in savefig
EDIT: I'm dumb, have to put the figsize into  the subplots parenthesis, do you think I should delete this thread?
 @JodyKlymak

Comment: I’m not an expert on stackoverflow etiquette but if you had this question others might, and hence benefit from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @JodyKlymak, place figsize within the subplots. From practice, it seems setting the figsize to be exactly the page size is not ideal. Furthermore, the main issue was calling two figures as I had an extra plt.figure(figsize=(8.5,11)).

```
fig, axs2 = plt.subplots(figsize =(8.5,11));
```